# Difference between $! versus a variable with rescue

Tags: ruby, exception

When rescuing from an exception, there are two ways to refer to the raised exception:

```
begin
  ...
rescue Exception => e
  handle_the_error(e)
end
```

and

```
begin
  ...
rescue Exception
  handle_the_error($!)
end
```

I believe they are interchangeable, but are they? Is there any situation where one should be used over the other?

Comment: Here are too many [`examples`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inline+rescue) except this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also think these snippets are interchangeable. But you should always prefer explicit variables to thread-global magic.

One case where `$!` magic var is handy:

```
result_or_error = perform_some_operation() rescue $!
```

For those who don't know that this line means:

It's so called "inline rescue". Format is this:

```
<expr1> rescue <expr2>
```

First, `expr1` is evaluated. If no exception was raised, its value is returned. But if there was an exception, then `expr2` is evaluated and its value returned.

So, in this case, if `perform_some_operation()` raised an exception, variable `result_or_error` would be set to an instance of that exception (because `$!` returns last error).

Comment: Could you explain what that does please?